# Monthly calculator for interest

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;    
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    public class FutureValues {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
      System.out.println("Enter the present value: ");
      int value = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter annual interest rate: ");
      double rate = input.nextDouble();
      double newRate = rate / 1200;
      System.out.println("Enter the number of months: ");
      int months = input.nextInt();
      int i;
      for (i = 1; i <= months; i++) {      
          double newVal = value + (value * newRate);
          System.out.println("The future value after " + i + " month is " + newVal);
         
    }    
  }    
}
```

I'm trying to get this to program to update the newVal to the next monthly deposit but it won't work for anything I try.

eg. "The future value after 1 month is 1004.79"
"The future value after 2 months is 1009.61"
and so on and so forth. I just cannot get it to update to the next value.

Comment: You need to calculate newVal inside the loop.

Comment: If the user enters the annual interest rate, then isn't the monthly interest rate equal to the annual rate divided by 12 (and not 1200) ?

Comment: When I divide the annual rate by 1200 it's making it so I don't have to make 5.75% into a decimal then dividing it again by 12 for the monthly update.

Comment: @AustinDerek consider upvoting and accepting answers if the problem is solved by comments or answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Calculation of newVal should be done within the loop.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;    
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    public class FutureValues {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
      System.out.println("Enter the present value: ");
      int value = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter annual interest rate: ");
      double rate = input.nextDouble();
      double newRate = rate / 1200;
      System.out.println("Enter the number of months: ");
      int months = input.nextInt();
      for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
          value = value + (value * newRate);
          System.out.println("The future value after " + i + " month is " + value);
         
    }    
  }    
}
```